# Google Cloud Run health check fails with Docker-Compose

Tags: docker, go, google-cloud-platform, docker-compose, google-cloud-run

I am trying to upload my backend to Google Cloud Run. I'm using Docker-Compose with 2 components: a Golang Server and a Postgres DB.

When I run Docker-Compose locally, everything works great! When I upload to Gcloud with

`gcloud builds submit . --tag gcr.io/BACKEND_NAME`

`gcloud run deploy --image gcr.io/BACKEND_NAME --platform managed`

Gcloud's health check fails, getting stuck on `Deploying... Revision deployment finished. Waiting for health check to begin.` and throws `Cloud Run error: Container failed to start. Failed to start and then listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.`

I understand that Google Cloud Run provides a `PORT` env variable, which I tried to account for in my `docker-compose.yml`. But the command still fails. I'm out of ideas, what could be wrong here?

Here is my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:latest # use latest official postgres version
    container_name: db
    restart: "always"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pass
      - POSTGRES_DB=db
    volumes:
      - database-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/ # persist data even if container shuts down
  api:
    container_name: api
    depends_on: 
      - db
    restart: on-failure
    build: .
    ports: 
      # Bind GCR provided incoming PORT to port 8000 of our api
      - "${PORT}:8000"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pass
      - POSTGRES_DB=db
volumes:
  database-data: # named volumes can be managed easier using docker-compose
```

and the `api` container is a Golang binary, which waits for a connection to be made with the  Postgres DB before calling `http.ListenAndServe(":8000", handler)`.

Comment: The default port is 8080 https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/container-contract If you want to use a different port `gcloud run deploy --image gcr.io/BACKEND_NAME --platform managed --port=8000` https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/run/deploy#--port

Comment: The message that you see is the default error message. Go to the logs and see what exactly happen to your service. And paste the log trace if you want more help from here!